# Authentication in Hosted Environments with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, hosting

Is it possible to partially replicate ActiveDirectory (or LDAP in general) for use in a Hosted environment? The idea would be to export/replicate an OrganizationalUnit or multiple OUs from the source AD to the destination AD in the hosted environment.

Are there any whitepapers, blogs, or articles on authentication with existing corporate domains in hosted environments?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at Active Directory Application Mode?  You can use the Identity Integration Feature Pack to synchronise data between your AD and your ADAM instance.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/adam/ADAMfaq.mspx

Answer (score 0):

Might be a better fit with ADFS - I'm not sure if ADAM supports authentication.

http://www.microsoft.com/WindowsServer2003/R2/Identity_Management/ADFSwhitepaper.mspx